# Grouping data by specific field from json then create element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

my code below is grouping the data and creates elements. However is missing the last group. I think my loop is bad.

```
data:
        [
        {"GROUPID":"A","QTY":3,"STORE":"NYC"},
        {"GROUPID":"A","QTY":4,"STORE":"CT"},
        {"GROUPID":"B","QTY":2,"STORE":"NJ"},
        {"GROUPID":"B","QTY":5,"STORE":"NJ"},
        {"GROUPID":"C","QTY":1,"STORE":"MA"}
        ]
```

so my grouping will be like

A   NYC-3 NJ-4
B   MA-1 CT - 4
C   NJ-5

so far my loop is creating Groups A and B but is not creating group C. 
..from ajax

```
  success: function(msg) {
 var c = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
 var myGroupid = c[0].GROUPID;
 var mList = "";
 var sum = "";

 for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
   currentGroup = c[i].GROUPID;
   if ((currentGroup !== myGroupid) {
       //compare if current record's group id is different than previous record.
       //if so, then means a new group. Send to plugin. 


       //call groupPlugin(myGroupid,mList)

     }
     mList += '<li'
     " data-group=" ' + c[i].GROUPID + '" data-store="' + c[i].STORE +'"</li>'

    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly and uniformly. It will help you and everyone else diagnose problems.

Comment: @MikeC , Thanks for the tip. I tried cleaning up a bit. My loop is iterating each row and basically comparing the current GroupID with the last one. If is different then Create a group and append the lines. However is not creating a group for the last row.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to have correctly understood your question.
I would go like this:

```
groups = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var groupID = c[i].GROUPID;
    if(groups[groupID]=="undefiend"){
       groups[groupID]=[];
    }
    groups[c[i].GROUPID].append(c[i]);
}
```

at the end you will have the associative array `groups` containing all the groups indexed by their `groupID`

then to get all the elements of a group (i.e. A)

```
var group = groups["A"];
for (i=0;i<group.length;i++){
    console.log(group[i].STORE;    
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I know how to get the groupid but how can i get the children? do I need to create the group array first then loop that array to find the children?